# Why was my edit on "can I sue an app" undone?

Tags: discussion, editing

I edited [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/28915/can-i-sue-an-app) post, mostly to fix its grammar and spelling.

Additionally, I edited the title.

It was originally titled "can I sue an app", but since *an app* is a computer program, it seems very likely to me that OP meant to sue a developer and/or a service provider; I edited accordingly and the edit was approved, but then undone.

I thought it was a mistake, so I re-edited.

This time it was [rejected](https://law.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/18253) on the grounds that it *"did not correct critical issues with the post"*.

Why?

The misconception that you can *sue an app,* which is not a legal person, instead of a company or individual developing it or providing a service through it, seems a fairly critical one to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it was reverted because by editing the question, you were answering it, at least partially; it might be a misconception to people that you *can* sue an app, and so that's worth putting in an answer, probably with an answer to the substantive question that you correctly identified.